# Find complement of a data frame (anti - join)

Tags: r, join, merge, r-faq

I have two data frames(df and df1). df1 is subset of df. I want to get a data frame which is complement of df1 in df, i.e. return rows of the first data set which are not matched in the second. For example let,

data frame df:

```
heads
row1
row2
row3
row4
row5
```

data frame df1:

```
heads
row3
row5
```

Then the desired output df2 is:

```
heads
row1
row2
row4
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try `anti_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df, df1, by='heads')
```

Answer (score 78):

You could also do some type of anti join with `data.table`s binary join

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df), heads)[!df1]
#    heads
# 1:  row1
# 2:  row2
# 3:  row4
```

---

**EDIT:** Starting data.table *v1.9.6+* we can join data.tables without setting keys while using `on`

```
setDT(df)[!df1, on = "heads"]
```

---

**EDIT2:** Starting data.table *v1.9.8+* `fsetdiff` was introduced which is basically a variation of the solution above, just over all the column names of the `x` data.table, e.g. `x[!y, on = names(x)]`. If `all` set to `FALSE` (the default behavior), then only unique rows in `x` will be returned. For the case of only one column in each data.table the following will be equivalent to the previous solutions

```
fsetdiff(df, df1, all = TRUE)
```

Comment: I like the use merge[df,df2] after setting keys. What is the inverse of this operation?

Comment: @HermanToothrot The answer is actually `df[!df2]` which is the inverse of what you've wrote

Comment: What if the keys in `on` have different names?

Comment: @JdeMello you can specify different keys- see `?data.table` look for `on` in the "Arguments" section.

Comment: AFAIK `fsetdiff(all=T)` will not help, it will treat whole rows as elements and subtract number of duplicated rows. X=1,1,1,1; Y=1,1; then it give two rows because 4-2=2. Antijoin will give 0.

Comment: https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/setops.html

Answer (score 28):

Try the `%in%` command and reverse it with `!`

```
df[!df$heads %in% df1$heads,]
```

Comment: Upvote for base R solution, although it might be not the fastest one here.

Comment: how does the syntax look like if I want to do an anti join and have mulitple keys/columns?

Comment: @Blind0ne: you could anti join on multiple keys by using `interaction` or `paste`. `key <- c("colName1", "colName2"); df[!interaction(df[key]) %in% interaction(df1[key]),]`

Answer (score 8):

Another option, using base R and the `setdiff` function:

```
df2 <- data.frame(heads = setdiff(df$heads, df1$heads))
```

`setdiff` functions exactly as you would imagine; take both arguments as sets, and remove all items in the second from the first.

I find `setdiff` more readable tahtn `%in%` and prefer not to require additional libraries when I don't need them, but which answer you use is largely a question of personal taste.

Comment: `setdiff` and `%in%` are pretty much the same function.

Comment: @DavidArenburg- agreed, which is why I think it's just a matter of legibility and taste.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, and that function is `match`.

Comment: @MaratTalipov I know that, this what I was implying

Answer (score 5):

dplyr also has `setdiff()` which will get you the

[image]

`setdiff(bigFrame, smallFrame)` gets you the extra records in the first table.

so for the OP's example the code would read `setdiff(df, df1)`

dplyr has a lot of great functionality: for a quick easy guide see [here.](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf)

Comment: does it handle duplicate as anti join would?

Comment: In https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/setops.html, says setdiff manages duplicates.

Comment: I opened the link and I can see there "Beware that intersect(), union() and setdiff() remove duplicates"

Comment: Anti join retains duplicate rows on LHS and ignores duplicate rows on RHS. By rows I mean only columns on which we join.

Comment: On the other hand data.table setops manages duplicates, but it still is not antijoin, https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/setops.html

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but for another option we can try doing a formal SQL anti join, using the `sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)
sql <- "SELECT t1.heads
        FROM df t1 LEFT JOIN df1 t2
            ON t1.heads = t2.heads
        WHERE t2.heads IS NULL"
df2 <- sqldf(sql)
```

The `sqldf` package can be useful for those problems which are easily phrased using SQL logic, but perhaps less easily phrased using base R or another R package.

Answer (score 2):

Another option by creating a function `negate_match_df` by manipulating the code of `match_df` of `plyr` package.

```
library(plyr)
negate_match_df <- function (x, y, on = NULL) 
{
if (is.null(on)) {
    on <- intersect(names(x), names(y))
    message("Matching on: ", paste(on, collapse = ", "))
}
keys <- join.keys(x, y, on)
x[!keys$x %in% keys$y, , drop = FALSE]
}
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text ="heads
row1
row2
row3
row4
row5",header=TRUE)

df1 <- read.table(text ="heads
row3
row5",header=TRUE)
```

**Output**

```
negate_match_df(df,df1)
```