# How can I perform a "setdiff" merge using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have two tables:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)

tab1 <- data.table(
  let = rep(letters[1:2], each = 3),
  num = rep(1:3, 2),
  val = rnorm(6),
  key = c("let", "num")
)

tab2 <- data.table(
  let = rep(letters[1:2], each = 2),
  num = rep(1:2, 2),
  val = rnorm(4),
  key = c("let", "num")
)
```

Table 1:

```
> tab1
   let num        val
1:   a   1 -0.6264538
2:   a   2  0.1836433
3:   a   3 -0.8356286
4:   b   1  1.5952808
5:   b   2  0.3295078
6:   b   3 -0.8204684
```

Table 2:

```
> tab2
   let num
1:   a   1
2:   a   2
3:   b   1
4:   b   2
```

Is there a way to "merge" these tables such that I get all the results in `tab1` that are not in `tab2`?:

```
   let num        val
1:   a   3 -0.8356286
2:   b   3 -0.8204684
```

Comment: Relevant post: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In this case, it's equivalent to an *anti join*:

```
tab1[!tab2, on=c("let", "num")]
```

But `setdiff()` would only the first row for every `let,num`. This is marked for v1.9.8, [FR #547](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/547).

Comment: is `on` operating like a `setkey` for the merge?

Comment: Given that my examples already had set keys, this can be reduced to `tab1[!tab2]`

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, yes, it does ad-hoc joins. Quite useful when you've large data and don't want to reorder it just to join. Or when order needs to be preserved. Also what columns are being joined on is clear (unlike `setkey` which might happen somewhere else in the code.. And the fact that it's a join operation is also clear.

Comment: @sebastian-c, I still prefer `on=` so that it's clear at a later point as to what's being joined with what.

Comment: Thanks! I started learning with setkey and will consider this option from now!

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, yes, I plan to update the vignettes to reflect this change. `setkey()` is mostly for advanced users (in my mind) and when the task involves repeated operations on the same (reordered) data (when having data sorted in RAM is quite beneficial).

Comment: `fsetdiff()` is now implemented - as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703077/5977215)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to do a merge and remove the rows where there are values from `tab2`

```
d<-as.data.frame(merge(tab1,tab2,all=T))
t<-is.na(d[,4])
d[t,][,-4]

 let num      val.x
3   a   3 -0.8356286
6   b   3 -0.8204684
```

Using `data.table` :

```
merge(tab1,tab2,all=T)[is.na(val.y), 1:3]

 let num      val.x
1:   a   3 -0.8356286
2:   b   3 -0.8204684
```

Comment: This works in this case, but it might not work if I have NAs in my data.