# How to get the residual dataframe from a larger dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
x<-c(10,80,30,40,50,10,20,80,90,100)
y<-c(15,10,35,45,90,65,75,85,80,90)
E<-seq(1,10,by=1)

data <- data.frame(x,y,E)
```

From this `data` i want to extract a sub - dataframe `data1`, that is included in `data`:

```
x1<-c(10,80)
y1<-c(15,85)
E1<-c(1,8)
data1<-data.frame(x1,y1,E1)
names(data1)<-c("x","y","E")
```

and I want to get the residual data frame (`data` - `data1`).

I prefer something that use `x` and `y` values to get the residual df, and if it's possible, a generally use code, without blocking the position of the data rows.

Comment: What is expected output and what have you tried?

Comment: and what do you mean by residual? how is it supposed to be calculated?

Comment: the residual i expect that is a dataframe that contains all the rows of data but not the rows of data1...

Comment: Are we talking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702960/find-complement-of-a-data-frame-anti-join) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the question, the desired output is a dataframe that contains all the rows of `data` but not the rows in `data1`. You can do that anti-joining the 2 dataframes:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(data, data1)
```

Note that this will return the rows in different order from the original dataframe.
If this is a problem you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(mutate(data, ID = row_number()), data1) %>% arrange(ID)
```