# Two data duplicate test

Tags: r, duplicates, data-manipulation

If I have 2 data with some same column names, and I want to check the different obsercations, how can I do?

Here is my sample data:

```
# dt1
ID  Name  ColA   ColB
2   Peter 1      2
4   Freda 50     4
5   Jean  8      10

# dt2
ID  Name  ColA   ColB  ColC   ColD
1   Roger 1      2     400
2   Peter 1      2     500    2000
3   Tina  3      50           20
4   Freda 50     4     500    300
5   Jean  8      10    89     54
```

`ColA`, `ColB`, `ColC`, and `ColD` are unimportant. I just want to check `ID` and `Name`.

Second, check `dt2` which rows are not the same as `dt1`.
Therefore, the result is:

```
ID  Name  ColA   ColB  ColC   ColD
1   Roger 1      2     400
3   Tina  3      50           20
```

Because my real data is extremely large, how can I check?

Comment: You just want an anti-join by ID and Name? If so, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702960/find-complement-of-a-data-frame-anti-join)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> library(dplyr) 
> anti_join(dt2,dt1,by=c('ID','Name'))
```