# Remove a Row by different values

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is an example of a DF:

```
v1<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
v2<-c(234,457,234,675,235,205,347,578,695,783,200,697)
v3<-c(528,659,102,236,358,562,987,102,235,474,888,362)
df<- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
```

For this example my intention is to remove the row with the v1=1, v2=457 and v3=659.

I'm trying different ways (subset or even []), for example:

```
subset(df,df$v1!=1 & df$v2!=457 & df$v3!=659)
df[df$v1!=1 & df$v2!=457 & df$v3!=659,]
```

However in both cases all rows with v1=1 are removed. How should I write this in order that just the row with v1=1, v2=457 and v3=659 is removed?

So the final DF should be like this:

```
v1<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
v2<-c(234,234,675,235,205,347,578,695,783,200,697)
v3<-c(528,102,236,358,562,987,102,235,474,888,362)
df<- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
```

Comment: Putting your row in another table and anti-joining is one way: `dplyr::anti_join(df, data.frame(v1 = 1, v2 = 457, v3 = 659))` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702960/find-complement-of-a-data-frame-anti-join Btw, you do not need `df$` inside `subset(df, ...)`.

Comment: Yeah, that does the same. I just need to remove the second row, the one with ALL that 3 conditions.

Comment: `subset(df,df$v1!=1 | df$v2!=457 | df$v3!=659)` because **!(A & B)** is **!A | !B** BTW: in subset() you do not need `df$`, so `subset(df, v1!=1 | v2!=457 | v3!=659)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the conditions inside a bracket preceded by exclamation mark:

```
subset(df, !(df[,1] == 1 & df[,2] == 457 & df[,3] == 659))
```

Comment: I've run this on my pc and on www.rdrr.io/snippets and it works on both. Please paste exactly what you've run.

Comment: OK. now I got it right... It was a problem with the packages I had loaded. I restart the session and worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Great! Thanks for remembering to accept an answer too!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be correct logic

```
df[!(df$v1 == 1 & df$v2 == 457 & df$v3 == 659),]
```

What you are doing is removing all rows where `v1!= 1` and `v2!=457` and `v3!=659`

```
> v1<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
> v2<-c(234,457,234,675,235,205,347,578,695,783,200,697)
> v3<-c(528,659,102,236,358,562,987,102,235,474,888,362)
> df<- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)

> df
   v1  v2  v3
1   1 234 528
2   1 457 659
3   1 234 102
4   1 675 236
5   2 235 358
6   2 205 562
7   2 347 987
8   2 578 102
9   3 695 235
10  3 783 474
11  3 200 888
12  3 697 362

> df[!(df$v1 == 1 & df$v2 == 457 & df$v3 == 659),]
   v1  v2  v3
1   1 234 528
3   1 234 102
4   1 675 236
5   2 235 358
6   2 205 562
7   2 347 987
8   2 578 102
9   3 695 235
10  3 783 474
11  3 200 888
12  3 697 362
```

Comment: ok but how I delete just the row that is v=1,v2=457,v3=659 but not the rest row with v1=1.... but the intersection of those 3 values...

Comment: The mentioned code does exactly that, removes 2nd row where v1 = 1, v2 = 457 and v3 = 659

Comment: @Cisco The result here has row numbers along the side 1, 3, 4, ... It seems to be correctly dropping only the second row.

Comment: I don't know why but in my R it removes all v1=1

Comment: OK. now I got it right... It was a problem with the packages I had loaded