# How to delete rows in one table, based on the values of another table

Tags: r, row, data-cleaning

I have a problem. I have two different tables. One that contains user information, and their ID numbers and another table that also has ID numbers and a second column that says whether the User is an admin or not.

Table 1

```
UserID AssigID Score      Date       Time

14532   23956   52      11.11.2017    401
12254   23956   22      18.11.2017    256
12644   23956   74      17.12.2012    365
11257   23957   45      10.10.2012    102
12667   23958   25      10.11.2012    109
```

Table 2

```
UserID  Admin

14532   TRUE
12254   FALSE
12644   FALSE
11257   FALSE
12667   FALSE
```

As in table 2 userID 14532 is an admin, I would like to delete the data of this user from the table1.
How to delete in table 1 the row where user is an Admin, based on the data from the Table 2?

As

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? Cut and paste and format your code directly into the question. It will attract more potential solvers.

Comment: In database slang, you want to do an *anti join*. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702960/find-complement-of-a-data-frame-anti-join) for ways which might be helpful if your table is very large (>100Mb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach with base R:

```
tab1[tab1$UserID %in% tab2$UserID[!tab2$Admin],]
```

which gives:

> ```
>   UserID AssigID Score           TimeStamp TimeOnTask
> 2  12254   23956    22 2017-11-18 13:16:00        256
> 3  12644   23956    74 2012-12-17 13:18:00        365
> 4  11257   23957    45 2012-10-10 13:29:00        102
> 5  12667   23958    25 2012-11-10 13:40:00        109
> ```

What this does:

- `tab2$UserID[!tab2$Admin]` gives a vector of user ID's that are not an Admin. The `!tab2$Admin` part makes sure only the ID's that are not an Admin are selected.
- with `tab1$UserID %in% ...` you select only the user ID's from `tab1` that are in the vector from the first step. This returns a logical vector with which you subsequently subset `tab1`

---

Used data:

```
tab1 <- structure(list(UserID = c(14532L, 12254L, 12644L, 11257L, 12667L),
                       AssigID = c(23956L, 23956L, 23956L, 23957L, 23958L),
                       Score = c(52L, 22L, 74L, 45L, 25L),
                       TimeStamp = structure(c(1510402260, 1511007360, 1355746680, 1349868540, 1352551200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
                       TimeOnTask = c(401L, 256L, 365L, 102L, 109L)),
                  .Names = c("UserID", "AssigID", "Score", "TimeStamp", "TimeOnTask"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
tab2 <- structure(list(UserID = c(14532L, 12254L, 12644L, 11257L, 12667L),
                       Admin = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                  .Names = c("UserID", "Admin"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```