# Delete coordinate pairs common to 2 separate data frames (R)?

Tags: r, pattern-matching, coordinates

I'm trying to  get the coords common to two different dataframes (`nodes` and `poly`)removed from the `nodes` data frame. The code below works if the coordinates line up element-wise, but not otherwise.

```
v1 <- c(2, 2, 4)
v2 <- c(9, 2, 7)
nodes <- data.frame(v1, v2)

v3 <- c(4, 1, 2)
v4 <- c(3, 2, 2)
poly <- data.frame(v3, v4)

newnodes <- nodes[-which(nodes[,1:2] == poly[,1:2]), ]
```

How can I achieve this? Desired output for `nodes` is:

```
  v1 v2
   2  9
   4  7
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is `dplyr::setdiff`. This requires that the names of the columns match up, but we can do that on the fly:

```
dplyr::setdiff(nodes, setNames(poly, names(nodes)))
#   v1 v2
# 1  2  9
# 2  4  7
```

More verbosely, this operation is an *anti-join*:

```
dplyr::anti_join(nodes, poly, by = c("v1" = "v3", "v2" = "v4"))
  v1 v2
1  2  9
2  4  7
```

You can find more options at [How to anti-join in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28702960/903061), though that question only uses a single column so some of the methods won't work so well for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new column of keyword by pasting two previous columns. This keyword helps you to find differences between two data frames:

```
nodes_k = data.frame(nodes, key = paste(nodes$v1, nodes$v2) )
poly_k = data.frame(poly, key = paste(poly$v3, poly$v4) )

nodes_k[ !(nodes_k$key %in% poly_k$key) , ][,1:2]
#   v1 v2
# 1  2  9
# 3  4  7
```