# Select rows based in rows of another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have these following data.frames:

dt1

```
Id  Mother Weight  
1    elly     10
2    bina     20
3    sirce    30
4    tina     30
5    lina     40
```

and

dt2

```
Id   Mother  Weight  sex  
1    elly     10      M
2    bina     20      F
3    sirce    30      F
```

And I would like select rows from DT1 (ID) based in DT2 (ID), this way:

new.dt

```
Id   Mother  Weight  sex
4    tina     30     NA
5    lina     40     NA
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two data.frames to find the rows in data.frame 1 that are not present in data.frame 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171426/compare-two-data-frames-to-find-the-rows-in-data-frame-1-that-are-not-present-in)

Comment: @akrun one answer is `anti_join(a1,a2)` - it's not _exactly_ the same, but it's pretty close and OP hasn't indicated any effort to search through the many similar answers on SO before posting.  there's plenty on SO on this topic.

Comment: @akrun, agreed!  it does seem to be somewhat of a code-specific cultural point on SO.  for example, i see way more dupe-eligible questions tagged as dupe in the python threads than in the r threads.  not sure why that is.  anyway, i do think this question is a close duplicate of several questions on the site.

Comment: @andrew_reece Sorry, but the previous question was very very confuse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find complement of a data frame (anti - join)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702960/find-complement-of-a-data-frame-anti-join)

Comment: @andrew_reece: There doesn't appear to be any serious interest in keeping the SO collection free of dupes. There's no serious penalty for failing to search and there is a penalty for downvoting and no rep for finding dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(dt1 %>% 
           mutate(sex = NA), dt2, by = 'Id')
#   Id Mother Weight sex
#1  4   tina     30  NA
#2  5   lina     40  NA
```

#### data

```
dt1 <- structure(list(Id = 1:5, Mother = c("elly", "bina", "sirce", 
"tina", "lina"), Weight = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 40L)), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))


dt2 <- structure(list(Id = 1:3, Mother = c("elly", "bina", "sirce"), 
    Weight = c(10L, 20L, 30L), sex = c("M", "F", "F")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
transform(dt1[!dt1$Id %in% dt2$Id,], sex = NA)
#  Id Mother Weight sex
#4  4   tina     30  NA
#5  5   lina     40  NA
```

---

```
d = merge(dt1, dt2, all = TRUE)
d[is.na(d$sex),]
#  Id Mother Weight  sex
#4  4   tina     30 <NA>
#5  5   lina     40 <NA>
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation of what your code does?