# how remove a group in a data set if there is a row from that group in another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 different dataset. one of them (df1) is a subset of another one (df2). there is a group called SAMPN. I want to remove all group elements in larger data set if there is at least one row from that group in smaller data set.

df2

```
     SAMPN     PERNO     
       1         1
       1         2
       1         3
       2         1
       2         3
       3         3
       3         4
       3         5
       4         1
       4         3
```

df1

```
     SAMPN     PERNO     
       1         1
       2         1
       2         3
```

output

```
     SAMPN     PERNO     
       3         3
       3         4
       3         5
       4         1
       4         3
```

data:

df1:

```
structure(list(SAMPN = c("   11", "   18", "   27", "   33", 
"   33", "   39"), PERNO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

df2:

```
structure(list(SAMPN = c(10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 
12, 12), PERNO = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2)), row.names = 90:100, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: when you say 'Group' do you mean column? Or row?

Comment: of course column. it is called SAMPN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find complement of a data frame (anti - join)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702960/find-complement-of-a-data-frame-anti-join)

Comment: In df2, you've got the column as numeric. In df1, you have it as a string with a bunch of blank spaces. Is that intentional? Or did you just paste it into the question incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter all rows where `SAMPN`is not in `df2$SAMPN`using this code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(SAMPN=as.numeric(SAMPN)) %>% 
               filter(!(SAMPN %in% df2$SAMPN))
```

Comment: how about if I have more columns to determine duplicates?

Comment: you could do something like `df1 %>% anti_join(df2)`.