# The fastest way to remove rows from a very big dataframe matching another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the fastest function in r to remove the rows in a dataframe if the same two first column is in another dataframe. For example, if the data frame A is as below(with more information columns):

```
    NAME    SURENAME
    John    Beer
    Rose    Pitt
    Bob     Kin
    Charile Kind
    Smith   Red
    Brad    Tea
    Kale    Joe
    Ana     Bread
    Lauren  Old
    Mike    Karl
```

and B as below:

```
NAME    SURENAME
Rose    Pitt
Smith   Red
Mike    Karl
```

I want B to be removed from A to be like:

```
    NAME    SURENAME
    John    Beer
    Bob     Kin
    Charile Kind
    Brad    Tea
    Kale    Joe
    Ana     Bread
    Lauren  Old
```

So in my case, A has 2 million rows (and 10 other columns) and B has 200,000 rows (all unique Name and Surnames).

Comment: `dplyr::anti_join(A, B, by = c("NAME", "SURENAME"))`

Comment: Hi Ronak, Thanks. Is that fast enough for very big data?

Comment: I have nothing to test this on. Since you have the data, you can try it and let us know if it was fast enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find complement of a data frame (anti - join)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702960/find-complement-of-a-data-frame-anti-join)

Comment: @Ronak, Thanks. I meant if there is any alternative function rather anti_join(),  I can run a benchmark and let you know about computational time. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Sean, from the link from @Cettt above, would recommend benchmarking against `fsetdiff` from the `data.table` package.

Comment: @Cettt, Thanks, Lots of alternative ways have been mentioned there. Appreciate it.

Comment: @caldwellst, what is the difference between fsetdiff and setdiff? aren't they the same?

Comment: @Sean the `data.table` package is designed to provide an alternative to structure to the `data.frame` that performs much better on large datasets, so will likely outperform the `dplyr` alternative. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) for more information on `data.table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested a benchmark filtering a data frame of 2 million rows by one with 200,000 rows, as indicated in the original post, where you can clearly see the speed of `data.table` relative to `dplyr`. Given the immense time `dplyr` functions took to run, particularly `set_diff`, I only ran each once.

```r
rbenchmark::benchmark(
  "dplyr_anti_join" = {
    set.seed(1)
    df <- data.frame(a = letters[runif(10000000, min = 1, max = 26)],
                     b = runif(100000000, 1, 200000))

    indices <- data.frame(a = letters[runif(200000, min = 1, max = 26)],
                          b = 1:200000)
    dplyr::anti_join(df, indices, by = c("a", "b"))
  },
  "dplyr_set_diff" = {
    set.seed(1)
    df <- data.frame(a = letters[runif(10000000, min = 1, max = 26)],
                     b = runif(100000000, 1, 200000))

    indices <- data.frame(a = letters[runif(200000, min = 1, max = 26)],
                          b = 1:200000)
    dplyr::setdiff(df, indices)
  },
  "dt" = {
    set.seed(1)
    library(data.table)
    df <- data.table(a = letters[runif(10000000, min = 1, max = 26)],
                     b = runif(100000000, 1, 200000))

    indices <- data.table(a = letters[runif(200000, min = 1, max = 26)],
                          b = 1:200000)
    fsetdiff(df, indices)
  },
  replications = 1
)

#>              test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#> 1 dplyr_anti_join            1  637.06   13.165    596.86    11.50         NA        NA
#> 2  dplyr_set_diff            1 9981.93  206.281    320.67     4.66         NA        NA
#> 3              dt            1   48.39    1.000     80.61     8.73         NA        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below using `setdiff()` from `dplyr` package, but you need to check its speed for large data frame (I am not sure about its performance then)

```
C <- dplyr::setdiff(A,B)
```

such that

```
> C
     NAME SURENAME
1    John     Beer
2     Bob      Kin
3 Charile     Kind
4    Brad      Tea
5    Kale      Joe
6     Ana    Bread
7  Lauren      Old
```

**DATA**

```
A <- structure(list(NAME = c("John", "Rose", "Bob", "Charile", "Smith", 
"Brad", "Kale", "Ana", "Lauren", "Mike"), SURENAME = c("Beer", 
"Pitt", "Kin", "Kind", "Red", "Tea", "Joe", "Bread", "Old", "Karl"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

B <- structure(list(NAME = c("Rose", "Smith", "Mike"), SURENAME = c("Pitt", 
"Red", "Karl")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks, Thomas, Will run a benchmark between setdiff() and anti_join() and update you.

Comment: Posted benchmark here. I was shocked by how bad `dplyr::setdiff` did!!

Comment: @caldwellst haha, then at least now you know `setdiff` is not a good idea