# Subset dataframe in R conditional on two values in paired list

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe containing several participants that performed a task 6 times. 
E.g. the data looks like this:

```
    subject blockN
1        133      1
17       133      2
33       133      3
49       133      4
65       133      5
81       133      6
97       134      1
113      134      2
129      134      3
145      134      4
161      134      5
177      134      6
193      135      1
209      135      2
225      135      3
241      135      4
257      135      5
273      135      6
289      136      1
305      136      2
```

Additionally I have a list (named excludeTrials) of pairs which participants' trial I need to exclude:

```
[1] 133   5

[[2]]
[1] 135   1

[[3]]
[1] 135   1

[[4]]
[1] 140   1
```

Now I tried to subset the dataframe based on those values. I wanted to avoid looping over it so I tried to solve it with sapply:
`df[df$subject %in% sapply(excludeTrials, "[[", 1) & df$blockN %in% sapply(excludeTrials, "[[", 2) ]`

and

`subset(df, !( (df$subject %in% sapply(excludeTrials, "[[", 1)) & (df$blockN %in% sapply(excludeTrials, "[[", 2)) ) )`

The problem is that with this lines it disregards the fact that both values need to be in the same row and the logical operator gives out `TRUE` for all blocks (1-6) by any participant being in the first element in the list.

Is there a possibility to solve it without a loop?

Edit:

```
structure(list(subject = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("133", 
"134", "135", "136", "139", "140", "142", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", 
"156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", 
"165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "171", "172", "173", "174", 
"175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", 
"184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", 
"194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", "202", 
"203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "211", "212", 
"213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "219", "220", "221", "222", 
"223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", "229", "230", "232", 
"233", "234", "235", "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", 
"243", "244", "245", "246", "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", 
"252", "253", "254", "255", "256", "257", "258", "259", "260", 
"261", "262", "263", "264", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", 
"270", "271", "272", "273", "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", 
"279", "280", "281", "282", "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", 
"288", "289", "290", "292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", 
"298", "299", "300", "301", "302", "303", "304", "305", "306", 
"307", "308", "309", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314", "315", 
"316", "317", "318", "319", "320", "321", "322", "323", "324", 
"325", "326", "327", "328", "329", "330", "331", "332", "333", 
"334", "335", "336", "337", "338", "339", "340", "341", "342", 
"343", "344", "345", "346", "347", "348", "349", "350", "351", 
"352", "353", "354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360"
), class = "factor"), blockN = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)), row.names = c(97L, 
113L, 129L, 145L, 161L, 177L), class = "data.frame")

dput(head(excludeTrials))
list(c(133, 5), c(135, 1), c(135, 1), c(140, 1), c(145, 5), c(146, 
2))
```

Comment: Please create your sample data using `dput( mydata )`.. You'll get better answers

Comment: If you convert your `excludeTrials` list to a data frame with the appropriate column names, you can use `dplyr::anti_join(df, excludeTrials)`. See [How to get the complement of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28702960/903061) for more ideas - though some of the answers would only work matching a single column, not 2 like you have.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `excludeTrials` into a two column dataframe and then use `anti_join` from `dplyr`.

```
mat <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, excludeTrials), names(df))
mat$subject <- factor(mat$subject)
dplyr::anti_join(df, mat)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I tried both versions and for me they still exclude the whole participant. What could be the reason that it works for you but not for me?

Comment: @carina__u Can you show your expected output for the example shared?

Comment: The expected output would be what you wrote:
#    subject blockN
#17      133      2
#33      133      3
#49      133      4
#81      133      6
#97      134      1
#113     134      2
#129     134      3
#145     134      4
#161     134      5
#177     134      6
#209     135      2
#225     135      3
#241     135      4
#273     135      6

What I get is:
97        134      1
113       134      2
129       134      3
145       134      4
161       134      5
177       134      6
289       136      1
305       136      2

Comment: In that case can you edit your post to include `dput(df)` and `dput(excludeTrials)` just as I have added in my answer? Maybe you have some different data structure.

Comment: what I get from dput() is too long even for my console. What should I do in that case?

Comment: In that case, add `dput(head(df))` and `dput(head(excludeTrials))` would be enough to get first 6 rows.

Comment: I think the problem might be that subject is a factor. So you were right, my structure looks different: 
structure(list(subject = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, ...), .Label = c("133", "134", "135", "136", ...)

Comment: Please edit your main question too include both the `dput`.

Comment: And: dput(head(excludeTrials))
list(c(133, 5), c(135, 1), c(135, 1), c(140, 1), c(145, 5), c(146, 
2))