# Extract rows from second Dataframe which are newly added compare to first Dataframe

Tags: r

I have two data frames, I need to find the rows in second data frame which are newly added that means my First data frame has some rows and my second data frame can have few rows from my First data frame and some other rows also. I need to find those rows which are not in first data frame. That means rows which are only in my second data frame.

Below is the example with output

```
comp1<- data.frame(sector =c('Sector_123','Sector_456','Sector_789','Sector_101','Sector_111','Sector_113','Sector_115','Sector_117'), id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

comp2 <- data.frame(sector = c('Sector_456','Sector_789','Sector_000','Sector_222'), id=c(2,3,6,5),  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Expected output is should be like below:

```
sector             id
Sector_000          6
Sector_222          5
```

**I should not use any other libraries like compare and data.table.**
any suggestions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find complement of a data frame (anti - join)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702960/find-complement-of-a-data-frame-anti-join)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are looking for similar entries in column `sector`. For all columns just remove the restriction.

We could use `dplyr`:

```r
anti_join(comp2, comp1, by="sector")
```

gives us

```r
> anti_join(comp2, comp1, by="sector")
      sector id
1 Sector_000  6
2 Sector_222  5
```

---

With `base R` we could use

```r
comp2[!comp2$sector %in% comp1$sector,]
```

Comment: getting below result: 
sector          id
Sector_000  3
Sector_222  4
Sector_000  7
Sector_222  8

not as expected, Id is wrong

Comment: What did you use?

Comment: both statements are giving same results for me. tried both

Comment: Are you sure you used the data shown in your question? I get the result shown above.