# Getting the unique values which have been removed between two datasets

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(haven)
df1 <- fread(
    "A   B   C  iso   year   
     0   B   1  NLD   2009   
     1   A   2  NLD   2009   
     0   Y   3  AUS   2011   
     1   Q   4  AUS   2011   
     0   NA  7  NLD   2008   
     1   0   1  NLD   2008   
     0   1   3  AUS   2012",
  header = TRUE
)
```

Now with the following data.table I have simply removed two lines:

```
df2 <- fread(
    "A   B   C  iso   year   
     0   B   1  NLD   2009   
     0   Y   3  AUS   2011   
     1   Q   4  AUS   2011   
     0   NA  7  NLD   2008   
     1   0   1  NLD   2008",
  header = TRUE
)
```

What I want, is to figure out, what **unique** values have been removed. For example, below I have removed two lines, but only one value that was unique in `df1`:

```
df1[, uniqueN(.SD), .SDcols=c("iso", "year")] # 4

df2[, uniqueN(.SD), .SDcols=c("iso", "year")] # 3
```

What I want is to extract the unique value that was removed from `df1`. Desired answer:

`AUS   2012`

I have a feeling this is quite a difficult question (or hopefully, I am missing something obvious). But perhaps someone can get me on the right track..

Comment: Do you need an `anti_join` ? `dplyr::anti_join(df1, df2, by = c('iso', 'year'))` . See the `data.table` version here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703077

Comment: Thank you Ronak. At first sight that appears to work very well. I'm going to experiment with it a bit.

Comment: One direct way to get the unique values (your desired output) while joining is to combine anti-join and `unique` function together . `cols <- c("iso", "year")`; `df1[!df2, unique(.SD), on=cols, .SDcols=cols]`. Note the use of the *exclamation point* in front of `df2`. This allows to perform anti-join.