# Merging two csv files to remove duplicates from output file using dplyr - R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I have two CSV files: One file contains contact information for survey respondents which we have yet to survey, and another csv files contains information for survey respondents we have already contacted. I need to make a new csv file of contacts we have not contacted and I believe I can do this by merging the two files in R and creating a new file which excludes the already contacted survey respondents through R. I am very new to R and want to sharpen my skills, but this task is a little over my head and would appreciate any help or advice

Comment: Please share a reproducible sample of both of your files with `dput(head(data))` so that we could use them to help you.

Comment: `dplyr`'s `anti_join` could be your new best friend.

Comment: Yip ... anti_join() will be your friend for this task!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702960/find-complement-of-a-data-frame-anti-join

Answer (score 2):

So, since I don't know your data, let's assume you have the data already read in using `read.csv()`. `df1` is the first dataset containing all people and their contact info. `df2` contains their answers. Both share the same ID (without unique ID, this won't work, but maybe you have to rename a column or two) which is stored in the column "customer_ID".

```
# this is my dummy data
df1 <- data.frame("customer_ID" = 1:100,
                  "address" = rep(c("saturn", "mars"), 25))
df2 <- data.frame("customer_ID" = c(1:25, 75:99),
                  "likes_apples" = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50))
```

You could extract the ID's from both tables and combine them. I converted it into a data frame so we can use dplyr.

```
df_combined <- data.frame("customer_ID" = c(df1$customer_ID, df2$customer_ID))
```

When you have the IDs together, you can group the data by "customer_ID" and count the number of data points per group. You store only those IDs which occur only once.

```
once_only <- df_combined %>%
  group_by(customer_ID) %>%
  filter(n() == 1)
```

You can then filter the data frame with the contact info on whether the ID is contained in the filtered data points:

```
df1[df1$customer_ID %in% once_only$customer_ID,]
```

I bet there are many better ways to do this, but I hope it helped anyway!

**Edit:** Okay, so I obviously learned something new from the comments. The way easier method would be:

```
anti_join(df1, df2, by="customer_ID")
```

Comment: You could also put your approach into one single pipe: `df1 %>% select(customer_ID) %>% bind_rows(df2["customer_ID"]) %>% group_by(customer_ID) %>% filter(n() == 1) %>% { df1[df1$customer_ID %in% .$customer_ID, ] }`. But I actually don't like this `{ ... }` style.

Comment: I guess I learned something new again :) But as a beginner this would give me even more headaches. Looks fancier though.

Comment: If you don't know them: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ and https://adv-r.hadley.nz/ will teach you a lot of `R` stuff.